# MongoDB run command with json return

Tags: c#, mongodb

My overall goal is to run a query that shows all the collections with the amount of data / counts and so on.

I found the following command/query and try to run it like this:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(server);
var db = client.GetDatabase(database);
 
const string mongoQueryA = "var collectionNames = db.getCollectionNames(), stats = []; " +
"collectionNames.forEach(function(n) { stats.push(db[n].stats()); }); " +
"stats = stats.sort(function(a, b) { return b['size'] - a['size']; }); ";
var command = new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>(mongoQueryA);
var test = db.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);
```

And the code fails here. Exceptions:

```
JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'var'.
```

My understanding is that this shoul be run as command?

Running the query in Robot T works as expected. Bonus the plan was to return the data in the following format ( Based on Json from running query manualy in Robot T)

```
 class MongoCollectionInfo
    {
        public string ns { get; set; }

        public long size { get; set; }

        public long count { get; set; }

        public long avgObjSize { get; set; }

        public long storageSize { get; set; }

        public long nindexes { get; set; }

        public long totalIndexSize { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `var collectionNames...` is not JSON.

Comment: Im aware, the question is how do i run this command / Query with the offical MongoDB C# driver.

Im clearly lacking some MongoDB knowlage, so im hoping to figure out where i went wrong.

Comment: As it seems, you only need to get collections via C# driver (look around https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoDatabase.htm) and do anything else in C#. As for the deserialization to MongoCollectionInfo use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: Im sure i could do: IMongoDatabase.ListCollectionsAsync and then run stats on eatch collection. 

But that would generate 80 queries instead of 1, im hoping to avoid that.

Comment: You might use db.Eval - however I would do it from C# as it is more maintainable. Do you expect real performance hits? How often do you need it be called?

Comment: Yea thats the ting i i was trying to do, This could be run via Eval. But thats being removed, so i have to go the you recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve can be done purely in C# as it looks like what you've attempted to do is send javascript to the server to be executed which is not how commands work.

To start off with we'll need to get a list of all the collections within a database inside the MongoDB instance.

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();

var db = client.GetDatabase("test");

var collectionNames = await (await db.ListCollectionNamesAsync()).ToListAsync();
```

once we've got the collection names (`collectionNames`) we can then go ask the database for the stats on that collection by issue a command.

```cs
var allCollStats = new List<BsonDocument>(collectionNames.Count);
foreach (var name in collectionNames)
{
    var collStatsResult = await db.RunCommandAsync(new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("collStats", name)));

    allCollStats.Add(collStatsResult);
}
```

The `allCollStats` then will hold all the stats for the collections and we can then use it as we see fit

```cs
foreach (var collStats in allCollStats)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"ns: {collStats["ns"]}, size: {collStats["size"]}");
}

// ns: test.test, size: 117
// ns: test.people, size: 5092
```

Also, if you wanted to use a typed result instead of a `BsonDocument` you can pass this in as the generic agrument to the command.

```cs
var collStatsResult = await db.RunCommandAsync(new BsonDocumentCommand<MongoCollectionInfo>(new BsonDocument("collStats", name)));

Console.WriteLine($"ns: {collStatsResult .ns}, size: {collStatsResult .size}");
```